# Azure: How to run a command as part of deployment process?

Tags: linux, azure, redhat, cloud-init

I want to deploy a redHat enterprise linux machine in azure public cloud whose packeges are all up to date.

Is there any way to run the command "yum update -y" (and maybe other 'yum install' commands as well) **automatically** as part of the deployment process or right after the machine's first boot?

Thanks

Comment: Are ARM templates as option? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI

Comment: Any updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a `cloud-init` config file(in YAML format) under the custom data section when creating the VM on Azure.

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - nginx
  - nodejs
  - npm
runcmd:
  - yum update -y #same as package_upgrade: true
  - npm i express -y
```

documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment)

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, It seem that It does not work for me..
As you suggested, Into the Custom data window, I past a short YAML config-file:
#config-file
package_upgrade: true
runcmd:
   - mkdir /mydir #for sainty check

None of the packages were updated and the directory "mydir" wasn't created. Do you have any idia why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, I will suggest the [VM extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/overview) or the CLI command [`az vm run-command invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_run_command_invoke):

```
az vm run-command invoke -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVm --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "yum update -y"
```

or PowerShell command [`Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-5.0.0):

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -VMName 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'sample.ps1' -Parameter @{param1 = "var1"; param2 = "var2"}
```

To update the packages in the VM, it should be after the creation of the VM, because the VM always provision the VM in that time, not update. So I don't think the cloud-init is a possible way.